# Comparing two scopes

Tags: angularjs, arrays, filter

I have two scopes with an array of data.

On a display, I ng-repeat over **service in listOfServices** and one of the fields is `service.rid` (note this is a fixed JSON feed from a 3rd party)

I also have another array which I use in an `ng-repeat` **items in FocusList** which also contains exactly the same field `items.rid` (note this is a firebase list which I generate on the fly)

What I want to achieve is this:

- Repeat over listOfServices
- If `service.rid` exists in FocusList SKIP IT

Now I actually suspect this is done at the controller level where I use a function to get the array of FocusItems and filter them out when constructing the scope. But cant quite get my head around it.

I have both scopes now working together on a single screen and in a single controller, I now need to do the comparison

Answer (score 0):

Create a new list.

```
$scope.newlist = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.listOfServices.length; i++) {
                     for (var j = 0; j < $scope.FocusList.length; j++) {
                        if ($scope.listOfServices[i].rid==$scope.FocusList.rid[i]) 
                           {
                              $scope.newlist.push($scope.listOfServices[i]);
                           }

                    }}
```